# Keyword Search in the Khan Academy API

Tags: api, search, video, keyword, khan-academy

I am using Khan Academy API to get topics, exercises and videos. I want a basic "search by keyword" feature through the API, where a user can type a keyword and the app displays a list of topics, exercises and videos containing that keyword. But, I'm finding that almost impossible as the API officially lacks features like keyword search and pagination.

I was doing a lot of research to find more documentation on how to do it to no avail.
Please help me do this.

Answer (score 0):

That's a big job.

This app does that - source code is available there:
  https://sourceforge.net/projects/khandesktop/
Also at:
  http://www.khandesktop.tuxfamily.org/
The app does not do exercises however.